# Can the Neo4j HA cluster 1.9 configuration be setup so only part of a graph database is part of the cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, neo4j, high-availability

Is it possible to configure and/or code so only parts of the graph database is part of the cluster?. So for instance only nodes with a relationship of a specified type will be part of the HA cluster – enabling that master and slaves can have “private” parts of the graph database and access to a common part.

Answer (score 0):

A Neo4j instance using HA is always completely replicated to the slave instances. If you need to keep parts of your graph private to a single machine, you should use an additional, seperate, non-HA Neo4j instance.